# Misunderstanding with eigenvalues in $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modular-arithmetic, determinant

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb F_2$. Let $p_1(\lambda)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $p_2(\lambda)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$, both of which are polynomials over $\mathbb Z_2[x]$.

For any polynomial $p(\lambda)$ in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$, it is true that $p(\lambda^2)=p(\lambda)^2$. Thus, we have the following relationship between $p_1$ and $p_2$:

$$p_2(\lambda)^2=p_2(\lambda^2)=\det(A^2+\lambda^2 I)=\det((A+\lambda I)^2)=\det(A+\lambda I)^2=p_1(\lambda)^2$$
so we have $p_2^2=p_1^2$ and $p_2=p_1$.

But it seems absurd that the characteristic polynomial of a matrix over $\mathbb F_2$ should always equal the characteristic polynomial of its square. **Is this really true, or have I made a mistake?**

Some consequences of this would be:

- the vectors fixed by left-multiplication by $A$ are exactly those fixed by left-multiplication by $A^2$
- the iterated map $\vec{v}\mapsto A\vec{v}$ cannot have any $2$-cycles, regardless of the matrix $A$
- the null spaces of $A$ and $A^2$ are equal

These seem impossible. What is amiss here?

Comment: Your third point clearly isn't true, as nilpotent matrices still exist. However, the characteristic polynomial doesn't see the difference between the null space of a matrix and the _generalized_ null space (the union of the null spaces of $A^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$). And $A$ and $A^2$ do have the same generalized null space (that's true over any field).

Comment: @Arthur So the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a factor of $p_1(\lambda)$ measures the dimension of the *generalized null space,* not the null space, of $A$?

Comment: that's true. That's called the _algebraic multiplicity_ of the eigenvalue $0$, while the dimension of the null space is called the _geometric multiplicity_. This distinction also applies to any other eigenspace as well, of course.

Comment: @Arthur Do you know of any indicator that, unlike the characteristic polynomial, shows the dimension of the null space and not the generalized null space?

Comment: There are a few. Like the minimal polynomial (comparing the multiplicity of a given root in the minimal polynomial and the same root in the characteristic polynomial gives you some information on this), and the Jordan normal form (a generalized diagonalization, where generalized eigenspaces that are not eigenspaces gets a 1 in the superdiagonal).

Comment: @Arthur Can you point me towards a reference where I can see a proof that the multiplicity of $\lambda$ equals the  dimension of the generalized null space?

Comment: That is general enough, and different enough from this question, that it's probably best if it's posted as its own question, I think.